# assigning onChange functions inside controlled looped elements (radix ui)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Not sure on how to reference the `onCheckedChange` handlers properly into looped elements, I could do it via uncontrolled setup with a form but i need it controlled for persistence.

```
const Checkboxes = ({ onCheckedChange, checked }) => {
  const checkbox = [
   ['one', 'label1'],
   ['two', 'label2'],
   ['three', 'label3'],
   // maybe i'll add the state and onChange handlers here, but not sure to reference them properly
   // eg. ['three', 'label3', onCheckedChange, checked.one]
   // then add another destructured param on the map iteration
   ...
  ];
  return (
    <div>
    {checkbox.map(([name, label, onCheckedChange, checked]) => (
      <Checkbox
        key={name} 
        id={name}
        name={name}
        className={someStyle}
        onCheckedChange={onCheckedChange}
        checked={checked}
      />
      <label htmlfor={name}>{label}</label>
    );
    </div>
  );
};

const SomeComponent = () => {
 const [value, setValue] = useState({ one: false, two: false, three: false, ... });
 return (
   <Checkboxes onCheckedChange={() => setValue} checked={value} />
   <Othercomponents />
 );
}
```